# View file is not showing anything in a controller file in core folder

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a controller file located in the core folder of my website.

I am trying to load a view file `$this->load->view('nolocation');`

however it's just loading a blank page, when i do the code above on any other controllers in the controller folder it shows properly.

Any ideas? Basically i want it to load a view when it cant determine the users location and not load the rest of the website.

thanks

Comment: Why are you having a controller file in the core folder ? Controllers are supposed to be in the controller folder.

Comment: As @Dum said, the controllers that are in core are used more for inheritance. You can do a base controller which has the data structure and base functions you require, and then create a controller inside the controllers folder and just extend your core controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the user's location in constructor of every controller class.

Example

```
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();

    if(isset_location()){
        redirect(base_url("nolocation")); //redirecting to the controller that specificaly designed to handle users with no location
    }
}
```